# Update webpack-dev-server laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack

Im using laravel with React and I am getting some security issues. According to [This post](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1566). I will need to upgradee my webpack-dev-server. Current my package.json file looks like

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.2",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.6.1",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "throttle-debounce": "^2.0.1",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "validator": "^10.8.0"
}
```

}

And my package-lock.json file has some mention about my webpack-dev-server version being

> "version": "2.11.3"

What is the correct procedure to upgrade my webpack to a non-vulnerable version?